# How to modify all models in sails to inject global attribute

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am working with sails framework and would like to automatically inject 2 additional attributes to be shared in all of the models: createdBy and updatedBy (fields to be referenced to the User model). To achieve this I am writing a hook and trying to alter the models

```
return {

    initialize: function ( next ) {
        sails.after( 'hook:orm:loaded', function () {
            setUpModelsCommonAttributes( next );
        } );
        sails.on( 'hook:orm:reloaded', setUpModelsCommonAttributes );
    }

};

function setUpModelsCommonAttributes( cb ) {

    // load models and process them
    sails.modules.loadModels( function ( err, models ) {
        if ( err ) {
            return cb( err );
        }

        Object.keys( models ).forEach( function ( identity ) {

            if ( models[ identity ].autoCreatedBy !== false ) {
                _.defaults( models[ identity ].attributes, {
                    createdBy: {
                        model: 'User',
                        index: true
                    }
                } );
            }

            if ( models[ identity ].autoUpdatedBy !== false ) {
                _.defaults( models[ identity ].attributes, {
                    updatedBy: {
                        model: 'User',
                        index: true
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );

        if ( cb ) {
            cb();
        }

    } );

}
```

Unfortunately, modifications to the models are not reflected and DB is not getting updated.

How to make sure those changes propagates, I got to be missing something here? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can setup default attributes in sails by editing `config/models.js`. These settings get merged with your models.

```
module.exports.models = {
     attributes : {
      updatedBy : /*...*/,
      createdBy : /*...*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I was hoping to control it per model with the flags ```autoUpdatedBy=false``` or ```autoCreatedBy=false``` when I don't want those fields to appear ( in reference tables ), but this would work